# HTTP of domain-1 loads domain-2 under HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, apache2, ubuntu-14.04

I have set up an ubuntu 14 as a server and pointed domain-1 without SSL but when I try accessing domain-1 with https:// in the URL it takes me another website(domain-2) hosted on the same server which is configured with SSL rather than showing Page not found error.

How do I avoid this? Here is a list of things that I have tried.

1. .htaccess won't work to redirect HTTPS to HTTP as the port 443 is not configured for domain-1 under V-Host file to reach the .htacess file.
2. Cannot setup `<VirtualHost *:443>` without an SSL and write a redirect here.

Have I done anything wrong in the code below?

domain-1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain-1
    ServerName domain-1
    ServerAlias www.domain-1
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain-1/

    ErrorLog /var/www/domain-1/error.
    CustomLog /var/www/domain-1/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

domain-2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain-2
    ServerName domain-2
    ServerAlias www.domain-2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain-2/html

        ErrorLog /var/www/domain-2/error.
    CustomLog /var/www/domain-2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerAdmin admin@domain-2
    ServerName domain-2
    ServerAlias www.domain-2
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain-2/html
    SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/domain-2/ssl/domain-2.crt"
   SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/domain-2/ssl/domain-2.key"
   SSLCACertificateFile "/var/www/domain-2/ssl/domain-2.ca-

        ErrorLog /var/www/domain-2/error_ssl.log
    CustomLog /var/www/domain-2/access_ssl.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one way to resolve this error, by the help of .htaccess file (HTTPS to HTTP redirect) but we will need to install a self-signed certificate.

Reason? As we access domain1.com the files that are displayed are from domain2.com so even if we create a .htaccess redirects on doamin1.com it won't take effect in order to avoid this, a self-signed certificate will help us in accessing the file from domain1.com and then the redirects on .htaccess file will take effect.

HTTPS to HTTP redirect

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

This video will help you in creating a self-signed certificate.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JLTWa62D0y0